# Find the number of combinations for binary vectors in the following case

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, combinations

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an $N$-dimensional binary vector. The first $m$ coordinates of $\mathbf{v}$ belong to a category, termed as "category a", and the last $n$ ($=N-m$) coordinates belong to another category, termed as "category b".
Let $L$ represent the number of $1$s in $\mathbf{v}$. For a fixed $L$, we define "special subset" as the subset in which the values (i.e. combinations) of $\mathbf{v}$ have the same number of $1$s from "category a" and also have the same number of $1$s from "category b". Note that, for a fixed $L$, one can have multiple special subsets. We also define "unique value" as the combination that doesn't belong to any special subset.
Let us consider a simple example where $N=4$ and where the first $2$ coordinates belong to "category a" and the last $2$ coordinates belong to "category b". For this example, we have:
For $L=1$: $(1,0,0,0)$;$(0,1,0,0)$ is a special subset and  $(0,0,1,0)$;$(0,0,0,1)$ is another special subset.
For $L=2$: $(1,0,1,0)$;$(1,0,0,1)$;$(0,1,1,0)$;$(0,1,0,1)$ is a special subset; $(1,1,0,0)$ is a unique vector; $(0,0,1,1)$ is also unique.
For $L=3$: $(1,1,1,0)$;$(1,1,0,1)$ is a special subset and  $(1,0,1,1)$;$(0,1,1,1)$ is another special subset.
For $L=4$: $(1,1,1,1)$ is a unique vector.

My goal is to find the formulas that give the number of special subsets and the number of combinations in each subset for fixed $N$, $m$, $n$, and $L$. Any idea or hint?